# C# Compiler That Can Generate Linux ARM Executables

Tags: c#, linux, arm, cross-compiling

I've been looking for some C# compilers for Linux and after a long search I've encountered some projects that are very interesting:

- [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)
- [DotGNU](http://www.dotgnu.org/)

But I haven't seen any approach on any of those to cross-compile applications to ARM Linux executables(`arm-unknown-linux-gnu`), so I want to know if there is any way to build ARM Linux executables using C# compilers like those or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [.NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework)?

> The .NET Micro Framework is currently supported on ARM architecture processors (including ARM7 and ARM9) and on Analog Devices Blackfin. The Porting Kit is now available along with the source code as a free download under the Apache 2.0 license at the Microsoft Download Center..

And:

> In February 2011, Novell posted a preview of the Mono 2.12 C# compiler, the first open source compiler for .NET Micro Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is capable of producing non JIT, native execution binaries for ARM. They integrated this into an SDK for the iPhone http://monotouch.net/ .